# Flutter "Test Drive" app doesn't display properly on AVD

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm just installing flutter into my android studio and doing the basic setup. I've done the instructions here: https://flutter.io/get-started/test-drive/

When I run the code on an AVD, I get the screen shown below.  device is a Pixel 2 running api 24 (Android 7.0)

I'll try with the latest builds, but would like to get this to work on older apis.  Any ideas?  Bug?

[image: flutter screen shot on emulator]

Comment: I've tried it with both a Pixel and Pixel 2 on API 27.  Same result (see image above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware acceleration with emulators may have some graphical issues at the moment. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13336. Running with `--enable-software-rendering` could solve this.